# Express, Node, Angular sending audio file to front end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, audio, express

I'm trying to serve audio files from a Node/Express back end, to an Angular front end.

The server side code is:

```
var file = "/filepath.wav";
res.download(file, 'testAudio.wav');
```

The client side code:

```
var testData = null;

this.getBasicAudio = function(){
  console.log("Requesting File");
  $http.get('/getBasicAudio', "FilePathRequest")
  //Success, return the file
  .success(function(data){
    console.log("File retrive Successful");
    testData = data;
    return true;
  })
  //Error, file not retrived 
  .error(function(data){
    console.log("File retrive Failed");
    return false;
  });
};
```

This returns the file all ok.

I'm trying to load this into a Audio object, as if I was putting in the file reference.

```
var audio = new Audio(testData);
```

But the object is null. 
From what I understand I'm getting back a filestream object from express, but I can't find how to turn this into playable audio.

edit: Is it because express download() only works with non-binary data??

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you put `var audio = new Audio(testData);` outside of the `success` callback? If yes, that's the issue, `testData` is a file only inside this callback.

Comment: So I populate testData from the callback, but access it later (the file loading takes place on the page load), when I access it I get some output.

When I change it to a text file I can access the text, it's just as an audio file that I can't use it

Comment: Maybe, by chance, the download of your text file is finished before you try to access it? Can you try with a text file of the same size as your audio file?

Comment: When I convert the mp3 to just the hex values it downloads fine (just as the hex). It's getting it down whilst still being an audio file thats the issue. When it does download there are a bunch or error characters.

Comment: Changed the serve side code 
`fs.readFile(file, 'hex', function(err, data){
  if(err){
   console.log("err");
  }
  // console.log(data);
  ms.pipe(req, res, data);
   
 });`

I'm now getting a variable with the hex values down. Cannot convert this to playable audio though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a file being delivered using this: https://github.com/obastemur/mediaserver

Code looks like:

Server:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  ms.pipe(req,res,"../../Node/TWLW/audio/examples/testAudio.mp3");
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Client:

```
var audio = new Audio('http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
audio.play();
```

In Express the files doesn't get returned in the response. Instead can be accessed by the url:

Server

```
app.get('/music.mp3',function(req,res){
  ms.pipe(req, res, '../../Node/TWLW/audio/examples/testAudio.mp3');
});
```

Client

```
var audio = new Audio('http://127.0.0.1:8080/testAudio.mp3');
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't read [**Audio**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) documentation.

> mySound = new Audio([URLString]);

**Audio** constructor takes an URL, not raw data. You don't need to download the audio file beforehand:

```
var audio = new Audio('/getBasicAudio');
audio.play(); // your audio file should play
```

The server code works as it is.